# Arcpy Point to polyline oversimplifying result

Tags: python, gis, polyline, arcpy

I'm trying to convert ~ 4k gps points into a polyline. I eventually want to buffer the points and to identify path coverage. What I am getting is an incomplete line. There are duplicate points and overlapping points, but I tested the below code with this dataset and it seemed to run fin

```
feature_info = [[[1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 7],[3, 7],[3, 7],[3, 7],[3, 7],[3, 7], [2, 4], [7, 2], [9, 5],[.5,0]]]
```

[Points and polyline to connect points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQDOm.png)
Current code

```
coordArray = arcpy.Array()
feature_info = []
newcoord = []
# Open a searchcursor
Input = '.../5PT175.shp'
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(Input,  fields="Latitude; Longitude;Timestamp;Speed", sort_fields="Timestamp A")

# Iterate through the rows in the cursor and print out the
# state name, county and population of each.
for row in rows:
    position = [row.getValue("Longitude"),row.getValue("Latitude")]
    newcoord.append(position)
    coordArray.add(arcpy.Point(latitude,longitude))
newcoord = [newcoord]

# A list that will hold each of the Polyline objects
features = []

for feature in newcoord:
    # Create a Polyline object based on the array of points
    # Append to the list of Polyline objects
    features.append(
        arcpy.Polyline(
            arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(*coords) for coords in feature])))

# Persist a copy of the Polyline objects using CopyFeatures
output = '.../polylines.shp'
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(features, output)
```

I would be happy to post the point file, but I'm not sure how to do it on this site. Here's a snippet though to test the code

```
newcoord = [[[-119.286071777, 37.165851593],  [-119.287513733, 37.164966583],  [-119.287521362, 37.164966583],  [-119.287513733, 37.164966583],  [-119.287521362, 37.164966583],  [-119.287513733, 37.164966583],  [-119.287521362, 37.164958954],  [-119.28754425, 37.164936066],  [-119.28755188, 37.164897919],  [-119.287559509, 37.164890289],  [-119.287559509, 37.164890289],  [-119.287574768, 37.16488266],  [-119.287567139, 37.164878845],  [-119.287597656, 37.164810181],  [-119.287590027, 37.164775848],  [-119.287574768, 37.164779663],  [-119.287582397, 37.164787292],  [-119.287536621, 37.16481781],  [-119.287498474, 37.164867401],  [-119.287506104, 37.164875031],  [-119.287498474, 37.164875031],  [-119.287483215, 37.164867401],  [-119.287475586, 37.164878845],  [-119.287460327, 37.164890289],  [-119.287460327, 37.164905548],  [-119.287460327, 37.164897919],  [-119.287460327, 37.164909363],  [-119.287460327, 37.164909363],  [-119.287460327, 37.164905548],  [-119.287452698, 37.164901733],  [-119.287452698, 37.164901733],  [-119.287452698, 37.164901733],  [-119.287452698, 37.164901733],  [-119.287445068, 37.164905548],  [-119.287437439, 37.164905548],  [-119.287437439, 37.164909363],  [-119.28742981, 37.164905548],  [-119.28742981, 37.164897919],  [-119.28742981, 37.164890289],  [-119.28742981, 37.164886475],  [-119.28742218, 37.164886475],  [-119.28742218, 37.164886475],  [-119.28742218, 37.164886475],  [-119.28742218, 37.164905548],  [-119.287414551, 37.164920807],  [-119.287445068, 37.16488266],  [-119.287452698, 37.164901733],  [-119.287506104, 37.164863586],  [-119.287521362, 37.164829254],  [-119.287483215, 37.164833069],  [-119.287483215, 37.164829254],  [-119.287475586, 37.164821625],  [-119.287475586, 37.16481781],  [-119.287368774, 37.164878845],  [-119.287246704, 37.164955139],  [-119.287193298, 37.164936066],  [-119.28717804, 37.164970398],  [-119.28717804, 37.16500473],  [-119.28717804, 37.165008545],  [-119.28717804, 37.165008545],  [-119.28717804, 37.165000916],  [-119.28717804, 37.164993286],  [-119.287223816, 37.164958954],  [-119.287246704, 37.16493988],  [-119.287246704, 37.164936066],  [-119.287246704, 37.164936066],  [-119.287246704, 37.16493988],  [-119.287246704, 37.16494751],  [-119.287246704, 37.164955139],  [-119.287239075, 37.164970398],  [-119.287223816, 37.16500473]]]
```

Comment: Are your GPS points in order along the path?

Comment: no, they overlap and have some sequences where the points either don't move or return to the same point

Answer (score 0):

Rick,

Have you tried the [Points to Line](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/points-to-line.htm) ESRI tool?

Comment: Yes, it returns the same effect as seen in the example above http://i.stack.imgur.com/UQDOm.png. My colleague and I suspected that the error was due to either the line overlapping or the line not moving when two sequential points were at the same location, which led us to the polyline approach